# viewWithTag malfunction.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have designed tableView through the storyboard, in one cell i have one button & one Label.
button is has tag-1 & Label has tag-2 on the storyboard.in cellForRowAtIndexPath i am accessing these like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@" i am back in cellForRowAtIndexPath");  

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;
   // UILabel *topicLabel;
    NSInteger rows=indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"row num=%i",rows);
    if (rows % 2==0)
    {
        CellIdentifier=@"LeftTopicCell";
    }
    else
    {
        CellIdentifier=@"RightTopicCell";

    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIButton *topicButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel  *topicScoreLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    NSString *topicNameLabel=[[NSString alloc]init];

    //some logic processing


            topicNameLabel= topicItem.topicTitle;

            [topicButton setTitle:topicNameLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [topicButton setTag:indexPath.row ];
            [topicButton setTitle:topicNameLabel forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [topicButton addTarget:self action:@selector(topicButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [topicScoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",correctAnswers,[answerResults count]]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

first time it works fine but when i came back to this viewcontroller, i have reloaded this again, but this time for two rows it works well. but for third rows it returns UIButton instead of UILabel for this line `UILabel  *topicScoreLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];` & because of this it is giving exception "unrecognised selector "[UIButton setText]"";

Comment: Are you sure you've set the tags correctly in both LeftTopicCell and RightTopicCell cells?

Comment: where are you adding button and label as subView to your table?

Comment: yes surely tags are correct seen more than 20 times

Comment: @Rajneesh071: added on storyboard

Comment: because you are setting tag [topicButton setTag:indexPath.row ]; and now the tag is changing

Comment: hey check ma answer if it will help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer ,because i am updating button tag through the setTag method in cellForRowAtIndexPath according to row number, it is setting tag to button as number 2 thats why it returning UIButton

Answer (score 4):

Because you are getting your button and label as tag 1 and 2 and then again you are setting tag value to indexpath.row, thats why it's creating problem

```
 [topicButton setTag:indexPath.row ];
```

So just set some other tag value to your button and label like 1000.

Then you access

```
UIButton *topicButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
UILabel  *topicScoreLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
```